# The number of permutations that can be written in two ways as a product of row and column permutations of a Young tableau

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

My question is related to an issue in the book "Young tableaux" by W.Fulton. Consider a Young tableau $T$ of a given fixed shape filled with integers $1,\ldots,n$. A permutation $\sigma$ in the permutation group of $n$ elements $S_n$ maps the tableau $T$ to a new tableaux $\sigma T$ in which the entries $i$ are  replaced by $\sigma (i)$. Let $R(T)$ and $C(T)$ be the groups of row and columns permutations that respectively map rows to rows and columns to columns. We consider a special set of permutations $\sigma$ that can be written in two ways as a product of a row and column permutation:
$$
\sigma =  \varkappa \, \varrho =  \rho^\prime \varkappa^\prime
$$
where $\varrho, \varrho^\prime \in R(T)$ and $\varkappa, \varkappa^\prime \in C(T)$. We then can divide all permutations that can be written this way in two sets which I call $S_+$ and $S_-$ and which are defined as
$$
S_+ = \{ \sigma \in S_n | \,\exists \,\varrho, \varrho^\prime \in R(T), \varkappa, \varkappa^\prime \in C(T) :\sigma =  \varkappa \, \varrho =  \varrho^\prime \varkappa^\prime \, \wedge \text{sgn} (\varkappa)= \text{sgn} (\varkappa^\prime) \, \}
$$
and
$$
S_- = \{ \sigma \in S_n | \,\exists \,\varrho, \varrho^\prime \in R(T), \varkappa, \varkappa^\prime \in C(T) :\sigma =  \varkappa \, \varrho =  \varrho^\prime \varkappa^\prime \, \wedge \text{sgn} (\varkappa)= -\text{sgn} (\varkappa^\prime) \, \}
$$
They are the sets of all permutations that can be decomposed in two ways in a product of row and column permutations using column permutations of equal sign (set $S_+$) or using column permutations of opposite sign (set $S_-$). In Lemma 5 of section 7.4 of the book of Fulton only the first set $S_+$ is considered where it is also shown that the number of its elements $|S_+|$ only depends on the shape of $T$ (the same applies to $S_-$ using the same argument of Fulton). In the proof of Lemma 5 I do not exactly understand why the set $S_-$ is discarded as it seems to be needed for the proof (perhaps someone can enlighten me) but at least I can see that the proof works if
the number of elements $|S_-|$ is different from that of $|S_+|$.

My question is then: is there an easy way to see that for any tableau $|S_-| \neq |S_+|$ or even $|S_+| > |S_-|$
(which I believe to be the case) ?

There are some easy limiting cases: for the tableau of shape $(n)$ all permutations are row permutations and for the tableau of shape $(1^n)$ all permutations are column permutations. In both these trivial cases $|S_+|=n!$ and $|S_-|=0$. I doubt that, in general, there is any easy formula for the sizes $|S_+|$ and $|S_-|$ but it would be interesting if there was one.

To show some examples of permutations from both sets I have displayed two cases in a figure. It turns out to be more convenient to define
$$
\varrho_\varkappa = \varkappa \varrho \varkappa^{-1} \in R (\varkappa T ) \quad \quad \text{and}
\quad \quad \varkappa_\varrho^\prime = \varrho^\prime \varkappa^\prime  \varrho^{\prime -1}
\in C (\varrho^\prime T)
$$
which are simply the row permutations on the column permuted tableau $\varkappa T$ and the column permutations on the row permuted tableau $\varrho^\prime T$. Then we can write
$$
\varrho_\varkappa \varkappa = (\varkappa \varrho \varkappa^{-1} ) \varkappa = 
\varkappa \,\varrho = \sigma = \varrho^\prime \varkappa^\prime = (\varrho^\prime \varkappa^\prime  \varrho^{\prime -1} ) \,\varrho^\prime = \varkappa_\varrho^\prime \,
\varrho^\prime 
$$
So the permuted tableau $\sigma T$ is obtained by first performing a column permutation on $T$and then a row permutation on the permuted tableau $\varkappa T$ and at the same time obtained by first performing a row permutation on $T$ and a subsequent column permutation on the permuted tableau $\varrho^\prime T$. This is illustrated in the following figure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hJoT.png)

In the example on the left we have the permutation $\sigma = (12476539)$ for a Young tableau of shape $(3,3,3)$ where we have the permutations
\begin{align}
&\varkappa = (147)(396) 
&\varkappa_\varrho^\prime =  (19) (34) (67) \nonumber \\
&\varrho^\prime = (123) (465)
&\varrho_\varkappa = (24) (35) (16) 
\end{align}
and we see that $\text{sgn} (\varkappa)= -\text{sgn} (\varkappa_\varrho^\prime)=1$
and therefore $\sigma \in S_-$.
In the example on the right we have $\sigma =(2847536)$ for a Young tableau of shape $(3,3,2)$
with permutations
\begin{align}
&\varkappa =(285) (36) (47)
&\varkappa_\varrho^\prime =  (384) (26) (57) \nonumber \\
&\varrho^\prime = (23) (45)
&\varrho_\varkappa = (23) (45)
\end{align}
and $\text{sgn} (\varkappa)= \text{sgn} (\varkappa_\varrho^\prime)=1$ and we see that $\sigma \in S_+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let
$$
P(T)=\sum_{p\in R(T)}p
$$
and
$$
N(T)=\sum_{p\in C(T)}{\rm sgn}(q)\ q\ ,
$$
then the coefficient of the identity permutation in $P(T)N(T)P(T)N(T)$ is
$$
\left.P(T)N(T)P(T)N(T)\right|_{\rm Id}=\sum_{p_1,p_2\in R(T)}\sum_{q_1,q_2\in C(T)}
{\rm sgn}(q_1)\ {\rm sgn}(q_2)\ 
\mathbf{1}\{p_1q_1p_2q_2={\rm Id}\}
$$
where $\mathbf{1}\{\cdots\}$ is the indicator function of the logical statement between braces.

Now
$$
\left.P(T)N(T)P(T)N(T)\right|_{\rm Id}
=|S_+|-|S_-|
$$
because given a $\sigma$, the $\varrho,\varrho',\varkappa,\varkappa'$ are unique as follows from the key fact of the theory $R(T)\cap C(T)=\{{\rm Id}\}$.

However, $P(T)N(T)P(T)N(T)=H_{T}P(T)N(T)$
where $H_{T}$ is the product of hook lengths of the shape of $T$. Moreover, the coefficient of the identity in $P(T)N(T)$ is $1$ again by the key fact above.

In sum, we have
$$
|S_+|-|S_-|=H_{T}>0\ .
$$

Comment: That was a beautiful demonstration, thanks! You use results from decomposition of the group algebra of $S_n$ using idempotents and arrive at the result from a different direction. I wonder if there is also a direct way based on properties of the symmetric group to deduce the result. The set $S_+$ has some special features in that it, for example, contains involutions. Could one by counting permutations of various types (for example using cycle structure) deduce the result in more direct way? This leaves a remaining challenge: can anything be said about the sizes of $S_-$ and $S_+$ themselves?

Comment: Good question, but my feeling is that it might be too hard. One could try to find a sign reversing involution. The problem is that bijective proofs about hook lengths are not easy to come by. See for instance the work of Pak, Panova and others about showing that the number of standard tableaux is $n!/H_T$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will have a look at it. Just a thought: we know that any pure row permutation and any pure column permutation is in $S_+$ and therefore $|S_+| \geq |R(T)| + |C(T)|-1$ as only the identity is both in $R(T)$ and $C(T)$ (the trivial limits show that this inequality can become equality). We therefore obtain the required result also if we can prove that $|S_-| < |R(T)| + |C(T)|-1$. It seems that this is something that may be proven directly by some kind of counting argument. Here we need an inequality and not a bijection.